# How can I add an hyphen to the chapter titles of my index without adding it to the titles of the actual chapters?

Tags: formatting, microsoft-word, indexing

I'm going to give you an example, just for clarity (I'm using Word). Here is what I'd like my index titles to look like:

> Chapter 1 - The Great Return
>
> Chapter 2 - Lucy's Dinner
>
> etc...

Whereas the titles at the beginning of each chapter should be:

> CHAPTER ONE
>
> The Great Return

(Note: Both lines should be aligned in the middle, but that's not the problem here)

I did a soft return, and now my index titles are like this:

> Chapter 1 The Great Return (without the hyphen)

Is there a way to add the hyphen to the index titles without adding it to the titles of each chapter?

Comment: Try a colon. See if it works. I don't use indexing (sorry)

Comment: I don't really understand why this matters. Is it really a question about writing, or about a software issue?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using Microsoft Word because you don't state otherwise.

Firstly, press Control Z when it does this to reverse the change. Then you can keep typing.

Secondly, you can go back and add the hyphen afterwards. Unless you have a large number of chapters, this may be the most efficient option. There are some annoying features of Word that I simply correct rather than solve.

Thirdly, you appear to have some form of AutoCorrect enabled. When it makes the change, there is usually a pop up allowing you to turn it off.

Comment: +1 for the helpful and correct answer. As a side note, I think you are right in your assumption that the OP uses Microsoft Word since they have a Microsoft Word tag.

Comment: I feel a bit stupid that I didn't notice the tag.